# variance of regression estimators

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

Given the regression eqn: $y_0= \beta_0 +\beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i$

I am having difficulty in calculating the variance of $\beta_0$

Here is how I proceeded:-

$\operatorname{Var}(b_0)= \operatorname{Var}(\bar Y -b_1\bar X)$, where $b_0,b_1 \text{are parameters estimator} $;

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(b_0)& =\operatorname{Var}(\bar Y)+\operatorname{Var}(b_1\bar X) -2\operatorname{Cov}(\bar Y,b_1\bar X)\\[10pt]
&= \operatorname{Var}(\bar Y)+(\bar X)^2\operatorname{Var}(b_1) -2\bar X\operatorname{Cov}(\bar Y,b_1)\\
\end{align}

I have already got the value of $Var(b_1)$,but i cannot prove $\operatorname{Cov}(\bar Y,b_1)=0$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that 
\begin{align}
b_1 = \frac{\sum (x_i -  \bar{x})(Y_i - \bar{Y}_n) }{\sum (x_i - \bar{x}_n ) ^2} = 
\frac{ \sum(x_i - \bar{x}_n)}{ \sum(x_i - \bar{x}_n) ^ 2 }Y_i. 
\end{align}
and that $Y_1,..., Y_n$ are i.i.d with $\mathrm{cov}(Y_i, Y_i) = \sigma^2$, hence
\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}
(\bar{Y}_n , b_1) &=
 \operatorname{cov}\left( \bar{Y}_n , \frac{ \sum(x_i - \bar{x}_n)}{ \sum(x_i - \bar{x}_n) ^ 2 }Y_i
\right)\\
 &=  
\frac{ 1}{ n \sum(x_i - \bar{x}_n) ^ 2 }
\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{cov}\left( Y_i ,
(x_i - \bar{x}_n) Y_i
\right) \\
&= 
 \frac{ \sum(x_i - \bar{x}_n) \sigma^2}{ n \sum(x_i - \bar{x}_n) ^ 2  } \\
& = 0.
\end{align}
The last equation stems from $$
\sum (x_i - \bar{x}_n) = n\bar{x}_n - n \bar{x}_n = 0. 
$$